# Purchase a MagSafe 2 Cord Only?

Tags: magsafe

My dog decided it wanted to make my MacBook Air Charger (MagSafe 2) his new chew toy. Is it possible to buy just the cord that connects to the charger and the MacBook Air?

I can only find the charger box (for lack of a better term) and not just the cord which is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the detachable AC Cord (http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht2346)

Amazon has one for US outlets:  [http://www.amazon.com/Power-Adapter-Extension-Apple-Macbook/dp/B009OA61UK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009OA61UK)
But, it is not an official Apple part, and (especially when it comes to power supplies) you might feel safer to stay with the sanctioned parts.

Your best bet for a *real* cord is to find a friend with a MacBook who plugs their charger directly into the wall, and ask them for their spare cord.

Comment: Apple power supplies fit a standard "C7" type of cord which also fit lots of other peieces of equipment - my battery charger cord fits my Apple produts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320 for details, a google search for "c7 power cord" turns up lots of options like http://www.amazon.com/Ziotek-Notebook-Power-Cord-Figure-eight/dp/B000BSLS0W